# Perl Multi Terminal application

Tags: perl, terminal, handler

Using Perl in Windows XP, 
system ("start") opens another Dos terminal window. 
How to make a "DOS" terminal handler, 
so script can print data to that new window ?! 
Cheers kes

Comment: I suspect it would be sufficient trouble that you might as well just use a GUI toolkit for your UI instead.

Comment: Why do you use system("start")? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want multiple processes (Childs)  talking to multiple terminals. "start" just simple way to spawn new terminal in WinXP. k

Answer (score 1):

Is `*.pl` associsated with perl, or are you wrapping your perl scripts in a batch `.bat` script? I'll answer assuming the latter.

If you want to run a script in a new window, you can `system('start script.bat');`.

The problem with this is the window remains open after the script terminates (if you look at `` `help start ``, you will see that start calls cmd.exe with the /k flag).

To get the window to close, you have to execute the perl script explicitly under cmd.exe with the /c flag.

```
system('start cmd.exe /c script.bat');
```

Now if your secondary script needs to talk back to the system'ing one, I would look into local sockets.

Comment: The original idea (most likely bad one!)was just to fork() child and assign the terminal for child's I/O. k